# xCode/Firebase Search bar cell fail

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have now tried everything (as far as I know), I even made the whole thing from scratch, but it still doesn´t work.

I have made a search bar which can search for data in firebase and display them in a tableview. If the user clicks on a profile in the search bar, a new viewcontroller shows with information about that user.

The problem is that if you start searching, then clicks on a profile, it shows the profile which started on that position in the tableview before the search happened.
This is what I see without searching, it displays the 2 profiles in firebase which is correct:[image]

Now, when I search for the profile "Lars Larsen" it filters like it should:[image]

However, if I now choose the profile by clicking on "Lars Larsen" it shows the profile for "Jonas Larsen", which was at the top before the search?[image]

This is the code for my searchViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, 
UISearchResultsUpdating {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

@IBOutlet var findKunder: UITableView!

var loggedInUser: user?
var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    databaseRef.child("Buyers").queryOrdered(byChild: "Personnr").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "Personnr")

        self.usersArray.append(snapshot)

        //Insert rows

        self.findKunder.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        return filteredUsers.count
    }
    return self.usersArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let user : NSDictionary?

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = user? ["Navn"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user?["Telefonnr"] as? String

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func filterContent(searchText:String)
{
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        var fNavn = false
        var personNr = false
        var searchBil = false
        var telefonNr = false
        var korekortNr = false


        if let Navn = user!["Navn"] as? String {
            fNavn =  Navn.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Bil = user!["Bil"] as? String {
            searchBil = Bil.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Personnr = user!["Personnr"] as? String {
            personNr = Personnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Kørekortnr = user!["Kørekortnr"] as? String {
            korekortNr = Kørekortnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
        if let Telefonnr = user!["Telefonnr"] as? String {
            telefonNr = Telefonnr.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }



        return fNavn || personNr || searchBil || korekortNr || telefonNr



    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let showUserProfileViewController = segue.destination as! userProfileViewController

    showUserProfileViewController.loggedInUser = self.loggedInUser

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
        showUserProfileViewController.otherUser = user
    }
}


}
```

This is the code I use to show the profiles:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {



//Outlets
var loggedInUser:User?
var otherUser:NSDictionary?
var databaseRef:DatabaseReference!
var loggedInUserData: NSDictionary?
@IBOutlet weak var Biler: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Navn: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var kundeInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bilInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var telefonNr: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var korekortNr: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var personNr: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Interesse: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Buyers").child(self.otherUser?["Personnr"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let uid = self.otherUser?["Personnr"] as! String
        self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "Personnr")


    self.Navn.text = self.otherUser?["Navn"] as? String
    self.bilInfo.text = self.otherUser?["Bil"] as? String
    self.telefonNr.text = self.otherUser?["Telefonnr"] as? String
    self.Interesse.text = self.otherUser?["Interesse"] as? String
    self.personNr.text = self.otherUser?["Personnr"] as? String
    self.korekortNr.text = self.otherUser?["Kørekortnr"] as? String

    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    )}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search bar is active and it does contain text, you should pass a user to `ProfileViewController` from the `filteredUsers` array and not `usersArray`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    [...]

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            showUserProfileViewController.otherUser = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            showUserProfileViewController.otherUser = usersArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }        
}
```

On a side note, you shouldn't us `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use Swift's `Dictionary` instead (for your case, if would be `[String: Any]`).

Comment: At var user: User, it says undeclared type "User"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code correctly, your issue is here:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let showUserProfileViewController = segue.destination as! userProfileViewController

    showUserProfileViewController.loggedInUser = self.loggedInUser

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]
        showUserProfileViewController.otherUser = user
    }
}

let user = usersArray[indexPath.row] // this is wrong
```

Since you filtered the results if the search bar is active you have to use your updated datasource

```
let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
```

Basically, you're passing the wrong information before you segue.

Comment: It says bad Instruction?